# What's the difference between `+deb10u1` and `+deb10u2` packages returned in the output of `apt-cache show`?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

Searching for `libldap2-dev` using `apt-cache show`, information for the following packages are returned in the output: `2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u1` and `2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u2`

What's the difference between `+deb10u1` and `+deb10u2` releases, and why are both returned as part of `apt-cache show`'s output, when I'm on the Debian 10 (buster)?

```
root@docker-desktop:/opt/sds# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

`apt-cache show`:

```
root@docker-desktop:/opt/sds# apt-cache show 'libldap2-dev'
Package: libldap2-dev
Source: openldap
Version: 2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u2
Installed-Size: 1426
Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Replaces: libopenldap-dev
Provides: libldap-dev
Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (= 2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u2)
Conflicts: libldap-dev, libopenldap-dev
Description: OpenLDAP development libraries
Description-md5: 2359036e8e1bd2b4b5d49233c1509ecf
Multi-Arch: same
Homepage: http://www.openldap.org/
Tag: devel::lang:c, devel::library, implemented-in::c, protocol::ldap,
 role::devel-lib
Section: libdevel
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/o/openldap/libldap2-dev_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u2_amd64.deb
Size: 331412
MD5sum: 779e367a1dd51c51d16ba6884542efe2
SHA256: 89885f64100e37ddcfa60bf757a0403a109cc31e515ceeb8b1c3d4750a17d33f

Package: libldap2-dev
Source: openldap
Version: 2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u1
Installed-Size: 1426
Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Replaces: libopenldap-dev
Provides: libldap-dev
Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (= 2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u1)
Conflicts: libldap-dev, libopenldap-dev
Description: OpenLDAP development libraries
Description-md5: 2359036e8e1bd2b4b5d49233c1509ecf
Multi-Arch: same
Homepage: http://www.openldap.org/
Tag: devel::lang:c, devel::library, implemented-in::c, protocol::ldap,
 role::devel-lib
Section: libdevel
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/o/openldap/libldap2-dev_2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u1_amd64.deb
Size: 331352
MD5sum: ea1492ecff7835d68e43c6fa2cc27d44
SHA256: 38c6f564d2077b8843ac47420e2ea93c3aac437336f51d52515be036becbedbc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+deb10u1` was the first update to the package in Debian 10 (after the release of Debian 10), `+deb10u2` is the second. You can see the differences between the two [in the changelog](https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/o/openldap/changelog-2.4.47dfsg-3deb10u3):

> ```
> openldap (2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u2) buster-security; urgency=high
>
>   * Fix slapd to limit depth of nested expressions in search filters
>     (ITS#9202) (CVE-2020-12243)
> ```

You can see both versions in `apt show` because, when you last ran `apt update`, both were available in different repositories — `u1` in the main repository (after the preceding point release) and `u2` in the security updates. `apt` will prefer the later version by default.

An up-to-date Debian 10 system currently shows `u2` in the main repositories and `u3` in the security updates.

`apt-cache show` has an updated record format which will show the source of each listed version in an `APT-Sources` field; you can get that information by using `apt show` instead of `apt-cache show`, or setting the `APT::Cache::Show::Version` configuration setting:

```
apt-cache -o APT::Cache::Show::Version=2 show libldap2-dev
apt show -a libldap2-dev
```

(`apt show -a` is used here because `apt show` defaults to only showing the candidate version.)

Unpacking the version number might help understand the `+deb10` part better:

- 2.4.47 is the upstream release version (see [the OpenLDAP release information](https://www.openldap.org/software/release/changes.html));
- `+dfsg` indicates that the upstream source archive was repacked to remove non-DFSG-free content;
- `-` separates the upstream part from the Debian part;
- 3 indicates that this was originally the third iteration of the Debian packaging of 2.4.47+dfsg;
- `+deb10` introduces updates for Debian 10;
- `u1`, `u2` etc. count the updates.

The part of the version before `-` only changes when the upstream source changes. The part after the `-`, including the `+deb10` portion, tracks the packaging updates in the tree of updates. To see why that’s necessary, check [the detailed package news](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openldap/news/?page=2): packages are regularly uploaded to unstable (as new upstream releases are made available, or packaging fixes are necessary), then migrate to testing depending on the testing migration rules. 2.4.47+dfsg-3 was uploaded on February 2, 2019, and migrated to testing on February 8. This was then included in the Debian 10 release, which means that 2.4.47+dfsg-3 remains as the base OpenLDAP package release for the lifetime of Debian 10. In parallel, updates continued: 2.4.48+dfsg-1 was uploaded on July 31, 2019. In August, an update to the stable package had to be prepared, but not through unstable (since that already had a newer version); so it got prepared as a stable update (in fact, a security update), with [the corresponding version](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.en.html#bug-security-building) tagged on to the existing version: 2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u1.